# How to remove DataGridView last row ButtonColumn Button c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am doing a windows application in c#.
Can any one help me to solve this issue. I have use datagridview in my form which is contain ButtonColumn and 3 other columns.  generates the form with total values of the columns in last row. problem is I want to remove the Button Column Button in Last row (Grand Total row).
In here I have use local database table as a data source for the DataGridView. Please help me.
[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N9KT.png)

Comment: Depending on how you created the data (sql?), put in a null value of an empty string and the button is without text. But the DataGridViewButtonColumn will always be a DataGridViewButtonColumn.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to reach for that cell after data is loaded and make it "less button". Following code comes from the top of my head and hasn't been tested, but it is just worth trying.

```cs
  int DetailColumnIndex = 0; //or whatever it is
  var LastButtonCell =(DataGridViewButtonCell)myDataGridView.Rows[myDataGridView.Rows.Count-1]
                                       .Cells[DetailColumnIndex];

  LastButtonCell.Value = null;
  LastButtonCell.FlatStyle  = FlatStyle.Flat;
```

Then make sure that when it is clicked, the eventhandler detects that it is the last button and does nothing

Comment: When I try to get LastButtonCell using this method is shows error as "No overload for method 'this' takes 2 arguments" on this line - [myDataGridView.Rows.Count-1,DetailColumnIndex];

Comment: Try `myDataGridView.Rows[myDataGridView.Rows.Length-1].Cells[DetailColumnIndex]`. I have edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you for responding me. But Its not work for me. It show button in last cell. small correction in your coding is need to change length into count. `myDataGridView.Rows[myDataGridView.Rows.Count-1].Cells[DetailColumnIndex]`